# How do employers implement selective website blocking?

Tags: https, tcp

I noticed that some places of employment selectively block employees from going on non-work related websites such as `https://www.reddit.com` in order to increase productivity and prevent procrastinating.

However, I am a bit confused on how this is being achieved. Doesn't `https://` make it such that everything (including the host) of a TCP connection secret?

In order for them to peer into the packet and see the host and reactively block it - doesn't that mean they can also see any submitted form passwords and sensitive session information?

How are they bypassing `HTTPS`?

Comment: TLS Interception, SSL Inspection, SSL Re-encryption. Edit: I believe you can stop the interception by changing the CA certificate from trusted to not trusted. Depends on how well the exchange is set up though.

Comment: @BenderBending Could you take some time out of your undoubtedly very busy day to elaborate your answer more? I have no doubt your remarks would be very enlightening to someone well versed in networking - but I assure you a more hand-holding approach coupled with some examples and definitions would be greatly appreciated by the rest of us.

Comment: No, I am not well versed in networking. I had the same question over the summer of 2017 and I asked a friend who is a system admin. I don't remember exactly how it works, my last comment was the TLDR version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Doesn't https:// make it such that everything (including the host) of a TCP connection secret?

No. TLS is about securing the bytes carried by the TCP. One should resolve the names you type in your browser and then TCP connection should be initiated to the server with the resolved IP. This information is known to entities like routers in the network and enables the blocking of connections to specific hosts.